# How to add offset to jquery scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the following code to animate scroll from a menu link in a navbar on bootstrap:

```
$("#subnavbar ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 600);

   // edit: Opera and IE requires the "html" elm. animated
});
```

At the moment, the fixed navbar hides the anchor underneath. How can I add an offset of 60px to adjust for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to subtract `60` from the `offset().top` of the target element, to allow space for the navbar. I've done this dynamically by getting the `height()` of the `#subnavbar` so that should you ever need to change it's height in ther future, you don't need to worry about breaking this code.

```
$("#subnavbar ul li a[href^='#']").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({ 
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - $('#subnavbar').height()
    }, 600);
});
```